# make the video fill the screen width and and remove the frame

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created this frame for playing the movie which resizes based on the user's screen size.

Now I want to be able to remove the frame and fill the whole width of the user screen using another function but each time I failed.

Now I'm using `injectViewportSizes()` function. I want a new function to do this:

1. remove the frame completely without affecting anything else.
2. stretch the width of the movie until it fills the whole width of the screen.

of course stretching the movie is much simpler for me than removing the frame ... each time I've tried to remove it the whole movie removes or a distortion occurs for the rest of the elements.
Here is the code:

```js
const clipSource = `https://langfox.ir/movie/movieclip/My_name_is_Edward_Bloom.mp4`;


const content = document.querySelector('.content');
const box = document.getElementById("box");

let video = document.createElement('video');

content.appendChild(video);
video.id = 'clip'; 
let clip = document.getElementById("clip");
clip.currentTime = 0;
let source = document.createElement('source');
source.src = clipSource;
source.type = 'video/mp4';
video.appendChild(source);
video.load();

setTimeout(() => {
    
injectViewportSizes(); // or goFull(); 
clip.play();
    
}, 3000);


function goFull(){
    // Remove the frame and make the video fill the while 'Width' of the screen
    
}

function injectViewportSizes(){

  let screenWidth = screen.width;
  let screenHeight = screen.height;

  let vwPixels = screenWidth / 100;

  let clipWidth = clip.videoWidth;
  let clipHeight = clip.videoHeight;

  screenWidth = screenWidth - (screenWidth * 0.10); // available space to put the clip inside
  screenHeight = screenHeight - (screenHeight * 0.10);

  let clipWidthNew;
  let clipHeightNew;
  
  if(clipWidth > clipHeight){

     clipWidthNew = clipWidth;
     let ratio = clipWidth / clipHeight;

     while(screenWidth < clipWidthNew) {  
           clipWidthNew--;
     } 

     clipHeightNew = clipWidthNew / ratio;

  } else {
    
     clipHeightNew = clipHeight;
     let ratio = clipWidth / clipHeight;

     while(screenHeight < clipHeightNew) {  
           clipHeightNew--;
     } 

     clipWidthNew = clipHeightNew * ratio;

  }

  let viewPortClipWidth = clipWidthNew * (100 / document.body.clientWidth);
  let viewPortClipHeight = clipHeightNew / vwPixels;
 
 document.querySelector('.box .content').style.width = `${viewPortClipWidth}vw`;
 document.querySelector('.box .content').style.height = `${viewPortClipHeight}vw`;
    
}
```

```css
video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -o-object-fit: cover;
  object-fit: cover;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #0b0e12;
}

.box {
  border-radius: 0.31vh;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, white 0 0.48828125vw, #f00c36 0 0.9765625vw) 0 0/1.380859375vw 1.380859375vw;
  width: calc(100vw + 1.380859375vw);
  height: calc(100vh + 1.380859375vw);
}

.box .content {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100vw;
  max-height: 100vh;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.262vh black, 0 0 0.6553vh rgba(0, 0, 0, 1), inset 0 0 0.6553vh rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  margin: 0.45vh;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"> 
</head>

<body> 

<div id='box' class="box">
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Note: it seems that this code snippet can't show the original frame correctly but it works in a raw HTML file locally.

Comment: When you say frame do you mean the one made using `::after`?

Comment: .box::after { background: none;}

Comment: @ sergey kuznetsov  How to add this using Javascript?